# Specifying trigonometric inequality solutions on an undefined interval - with or without negative angles?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Suppose I'm trying solve the following inequality for $x$, on an unspecified interval:

$$\cos2x \ge -\tfrac{1}{2}$$

An obvious solution would be $x \in [-\frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi, \frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi]$ - (where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$).

---

What I'm wondering is if the solution could be written such that it omits the initial negative angle, for example: $x \in [k\pi, \frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi] \cup [\frac{2\pi}{3} + k\pi, \pi + k\pi]$.

Both solutions cover the same region of the unit circle (sorry if my terminology isn't good here), however only the first one includes a negative solution (in the lower bound).

I'm wondering whether both solutions are correct/valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both solutions are valid. However, it depends what you are using them for: the first solution helps us find the solutions in $[-\pi/2 + k\pi, \pi/2 + k\pi]$, while the second solution helps us find the solutions in $[k\pi, (k+1)\pi]$.

The first solution is more natural as it respects the shape of the cosine graph, but as you have noticed, you still need a bit more work to find the solutions in say, $[0, 2\pi]$. The second solution is better suited to $[0, \pi]$ at the cost of being more lengthy. So it is all a matter of preference: personally, I would write:

$$x \in [k\pi, (k+1)\pi] \setminus \left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}, k \pi +\frac{2 \pi}{3}\right)$$

where the backslash represents the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), so as one region excluding another region.